# What would be the hypothetical phonological range of canines based on their physiology?

Tags: phonology, syllables

There are all kinds of videos showcasing "talking" dogs like huskies jabbering away, but I'm curious: In theory (in a world where dogs could have human brains) what would they physiologically be capable of saying? What syllables would be limited or impossible due to their physiology?

Comment: I assume you're asking just about the physiology of the vocal tract articulation and the resulting acoustics, not whether their brains have the capacity to send fine motor-control programs (or, for that matter, to analyze things into phonemes in the first place), right?

Comment: Yes. If a dog had a human brain, what would be the range of sounds they could make?

Answer (score 3):

Huskies are phonologically incapable of forming anything (phonology is about the grammar of sound systems). They are phonetically capable of things that might vague resemble speech sounds. It is an interesting and under-studies quirk of the breed that they are closer to parrots in their vocal abilities. I believe that the differences are actually brain-based and not based on articulatory anatomy, since their anatomy is not radically different from bark-only breeds. Basically, they can produce a range of voiced vocoids, with some laryngeal and back-tongue trilling. We love to interpret their outputs as human language sounds, but most of that comes from our interpretive efforts and not what they are doing.

Comment: For some reason, nobody ever manages to record the part after the demonstration, where the Huskies turns to his owner and says "Why did you have me say 'Hello' on your YouTube video, when you know I have a problem with both fricatives and laterals?" :)

Comment: That's cuz they say it with their eyes.

Comment: If you had a werewolf, for example, a human stuck in a wolf's body, how well would they be able to communicate? Asking for creative writing purposes.

Comment: Hard to tell. They can't control their "speech anatomy" like we can, which is about brains and not just meat. You'd need to get a specialist in dog and human anatomy to field that.

Comment: @AlyssaShurtz As far as I know, people haven't done much research on what the wolf muscles might theoretically be acoustically capable of. It seems like it would make more sense to focus on our closest relatives and reconstructions of our ancestors, or really interesting cases like parrots, or very simple animals. So, if there are any non-obvious ways in which dogs or wolves might be better than chimps at human sounds, there's a good chance nobody's found that out.

Comment: @AlyssaShurtz Meanwhile: if you just stick a human brain in a wolf body, it probably won't be able to do much. Wolves don't have nerves to carry the signals from a human brain. If you've got human nerves most of the way out, they're not made to control wolf muscles, so that's probably even more useless. You'd probably have o use some kind of superscience or magic that could design something as complicated as the human nervous system without millions of years of evolutionary trial and error, and then use that to grow a wolfman from a fetus, which probably won't fit your story.

Answer (score 1):

When you drill down, dogs actually have quite a bit of potential for phonemic inventory, even without human innervation. Dog vocalization basically has a few degrees of freedom:

- Pitch
- Mouth open/close, loosely analogous to open/close axis of vowel chart
- voicing/voiceless
- limited amounts of constriction and trilling

I'm going to actually disagree with the other answer slightly; dogs clearly have *some* systematic phonological meaning (growling usually indicates agitation or intesity, whining is distress or submission). It's just that the complexity of it compared to human phonology is like comparing a toyboat to an aircraft carrier.

This gives a quite limited consonant inventory, which I would transcribe as /k/ for a glottal-stop-esque sound, /r/ for the growl, and maybe something like /h~f/ for the throat constriction sound. I'm not even gonna try for narrow transcription, because a) dogs rely heavily on allophony b) I don't think the IPA is well-equipped for this task c) I'm on mobile at the moment and don't want to make this more tedious than it needs to be. We can use double letters to denote voiced vs voiceless.

Vowels are an interesting story. Dogs don't seem to "use" vowels in the sense of a relatively static formant filter. Rather, it's almost like the modulation of the envelope is what matters, like diphthongs for humans. Let's give them an /a/, /i/ and /u/, because that's what I hear, but they are almost always paired or higher groupings.

Then there's tones. This is where dogs have the potential to be most expressive, as you can modulate tons of information into sound. In practice, the "phonotactics" seem to limit to a few tone sequences. Tone 1: constant /a/, tone 2: rising /á/, tone 3: modulating (fall/rise like Chinese tones, but also rise/fall. I'm going to call both /ǎ/), tone 4: falling /à/.

There's also the whine "tone", which is more of a register than a tone. I'm just going to use /ı/ since it seems not to be modulated.

There's arguably some sort of nasalation or r-colored vowel in there as well, as evidenced by some languages transcribing a dog sound onomatopoeia as some variant of "arf", "ark", "wan", or "wang". Kind of hard to transcribe, so I'll omit it.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-colored_vowel

Duration is another axis dogs can modulate, but it does not seem to be phonetic.

So that gives us the "vowels" /a/, /i/, /u/, with 4 tones each. /I/ is kind of standalone, for a total of 13 "vowels". There's unvoiced /r/ /h/ /k/, voiced /rr/, maybe a /hh/, call it 5 consonants.

The actual phonotactics restrict what "words" can be formed, but there's a surprising number of valid, distinct phonemes possible. I estimate there's probably over a hundred realizable phonemes. How many of those are allophonic? No idea, probably the majority of sounds are allophonic in practice. That still leaves dozens of unique "words" that are 100% possible with dog physiology.

Your classic dog "bark" is actually closer to /àok/.

I can easily discern the difference when my poodle "says" *aoh* (hey, there's something odd/ gimme attention),  *àok* (hey! Something important!), *áih* (something I want is out of reach/I'm stuck/door is shut), *arh* (play with me), and *hiàh* (please play with me!?). The actual sound variation is much wider, the transcription is limited, but so is the information density. Basically it's all variants on "I want something", "warning", or "stop that", with a bit of nuance for how intense the request/warning is. Basically the vocab of an 12-18 month old toddler.

In actual dogs, syntax is basically nonexistent. There's maybe a sliver of evidence that dogs can use a very rudimentary object-action grammer, with Bunny and the fluent pet buttons, but this is very tentative and disputed. There certainly is no recursive grammar, the hallmark of human language. But given a human brain, no doubt dogs could utilize complex syntax and grammar.

There's a lot of nuance there if you listen for it.

Tangentially related but too cool not to share, check out C’ą̂ą́r, a conlang for hypothetical sapient corvids. https://hailman.conlang.org/caar/